# Validar contraseña y ejecutar ruta en Laravel con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Estoy trabajando con un crud, pero ya funciona perfectamente, pero ahora necesito poner una contraseña para poder eliminar un elemento.

Actualmente no se me ocurre nada.

Por ahora tengo esto.

```
function Validate() {
 var pass = prompt("Introduzca contraseña:", "");
                 
  if (pass == 'japon') {
   return true;
   }else {
   return false;
   }
  }
```

y en mi HTML

```
<a onclick="return Validate()" href="{{route("descartar",$value->sku)}}" class="ml-3">
 Eliminar              
</a>
```

Y quiero que cuando la contraseña coincida que se ejecute la ruta de laravel y si no coincide solo muestre un mensaje

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Y esa contraseña sera fija o viene de una base de datos?

Comment: Sera una contraseña fija

Comment: Espero que sea un trabajo escolar, si es profesional estas vulnerando el sistema de una forma descomunal. El código que pones es Javascript, pero pides que se haga con Laravel. ¿En dónde quieres que se implemente el código?

Comment: Haz una petición con ajax. Ajax te devolverá una promesa, en caso de que todo salga bien puedes enviar un mensaje desde el servidor (REGISTRO ELIMINADO CORRECTAMENTE por ejemplo). Si estas usando webpack en laravel puedes usar una libreria llamada axios, que hace mucho mas sencillas las peticiones al server mediante ajax. Pero te lo recomiendo solo si harás muchas peticiones de este tipo, caso contrario, no vale la pena instalar una librería para hacer una sola petición.

Comment: No te compliques, a parte desde js se puede manipular la data, quiere decir que alguien puede ver la contraseña, yo optaria por usar un guard o una policie si quieres restringir que ciertos usuarios puedan eliminar datos